# update fields of a 'pass and confirm' form

Tags: php, mysql, post, passwords

the user from his private area send to me a request to update his own level. 
There are three types of levels, in order from bottom, 'utente', 'delegato', and superuser.

I have in fact prepared for the level 'utente' and the level 'delegato' a page where by filling in a simple form, they update the field named upgrade_liv from 'no' (default value) to 'si'.

I built a php page where I get these requests (i'm superuser, naturally); i built it with an array through I see all users who have the value 'si' in the upgrade_liv's field. this is the form:

```
$query_ver_liv_up="SELECT * from utenti WHERE upgrade_liv = 'si' order by id";
$result_ver_liv_up= mysql_query($query_ver_liv_up); 
$utente_piu = 'delegato';
$delegato_piu = 'superuser';

// tabella upgrade
echo '<table border="1" width="1260px" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">';
echo '<tr bgcolor="#bcc500"><td style="border: black 0px solid" height="30px"><b><center>UPGRADE LIVELLO UTENTI</center></b></td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo '<table border="1" width="1260px" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:5px;">';
echo '<form method="post" name="ver_liv_upg_yes">';  
echo '<tr bgcolor="#bb6500">';
echo '<td width="100px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Numero id</center></b></td>';
echo '<td width="300px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Nome e cognome</b></center></td>';
echo '<td width="120px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Livello</b></center></td>';
echo '<td width="120px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Upgrade</b></center></td>';
echo '<td width="180px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Livello richiesto</b></center></td>';
echo '<td width="120px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Pass</b></center></td>';
echo '<td width="120px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Conferma</b></center></td>';
echo '<td width="100px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Approva</b></center></td>';
echo '<td width="100px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Nega</b></center></td>';
echo '</tr>';
while($row_ver_liv_up = mysql_fetch_array($result_ver_liv_up))  
{


echo '<tr>';
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center>'.$row_ver_liv_up['id']."</center></td>";
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center>'.$row_ver_liv_up['nome']."&nbsp;" .$row_ver_liv_up['cognome']."</center></td>";
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center>'.$row_ver_liv_up['tipo_user']."</center></td>";
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center>'.$row_ver_liv_up['upgrade_liv']."</center></td>";
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center>';
if ($row_ver_liv_up['tipo_user'] == 'utente'){
echo $utente_piu;}
if ($row_ver_liv_up['tipo_user'] == "delegato"){
echo $delegato_piu;}
echo '</center></td>';
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center>
      <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==\'pass\') this.value=\'\';" /></center></td>';
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center>
      <input name="conferma" type="password" id="conferma" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==\'conferma\') this.value=\'\';" /></center></td>';
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center><input style="width: 100px;" name="ver_liv_upg_yes" type="submit" value="Approva" /></center></td>';
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center><input style="width: 100px;" name="ver_liv_upg_no" type="submit" value="Nega" /></center></td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</form>';
echo '</table>';
```

the code php i've used is:

```
if(isset($_POST['ver_liv_upg_yes'])) 
    {
    $pass = (isset($_POST['pass'])) ? trim($_POST['pass']) : '';  
    $conferma = (isset($_POST['conferma'])) ? trim($_POST['conferma']) : ''; 

    $query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['login'] . "' LIMIT 1");  
    $loggato =  $_SESSION['login'];

    // Controllo la Password
    $pass = $_POST['pass']; 
    if($pass == ""){echo'Campo password non compilato!<br>'; exit();}   
    elseif(strlen($pass) < 4 || strlen($pass) > 12)
        {echo('Password troppo corta o troppo lunga<br>');exit();   }   

    // Controllo la conferma della Password
    $conferma = $_POST['conferma']; 
    if($conferma == ""){echo'Campo conferma password non compilato!<br>'; exit();}      
     elseif(strlen($conferma) < 4 || strlen($conferma) > 12)
        {echo('Conferma della password troppo corta o troppo lunga<br>');exit();    }

    // Controllo se password e conferma sono uguali 
    if($pass != $conferma){echo'I campi password e conferma password devono coincidere!<br>';exit();}       
    $query_pass =  mysql_query("SELECT pass FROM utenti WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['login'] . "' LIMIT 1");  
    $row_pass = mysql_fetch_array($query_pass);
    $pass2 = $row_pass['pass'];
    $pass = md5($pass);     

    // Crypto la password e la confronto con quella nel database
    if($pass != $row_pass['pass']){echo('Password errata');exit();} 


    $query_ver_liv_up = "SELECT * from utenti WHERE upgrade_liv = 'si' ";
    $result_ver_liv_up = mysql_query($query_ver_liv_up);    
    $row_ver_liv_up = mysql_fetch_array($result_ver_liv_up);
    // Se ha trovato un record
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) 
    {

    // prelevo l'id dal database
    $login = mysql_fetch_array($query); 


    // preparo la query di aggiornamento
    $query_mod2 = "UPDATE utenti SET upgrade_liv = 'no', tipo_user ='delegato'   WHERE id = '" . $row_ver_liv_up['id']. "'  ";  

    // invio la query
    $result = mysql_query($query_mod2); 
    {header('Location: privata.php'); exit; }
}   
}
```

suppose i have only two users they want to change their level:
if i insert pass and confirm in the first row, it appears the echo 'Campo password non compilato' (pass not fill), but if i insert them in the second row, (in the image i've post you can see the user toy story on the second row), my php code change on db the fields of the user peppa pig!!!

how can do to resolve that? where my code is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I understood where is the error: i have put

```
echo '<form method="post" name="ver_liv_up">';
```

before

```
 while($row_ver_liv_up = mysql_fetch_array($result_ver_liv_up)) 
{}
```

if i write the form in this way:

```
echo '<table border="1" width="1260px" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:5px;">';
echo '<tr bgcolor="#bb6500">';
echo '<td width="100px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Numero id</center></b></td>';
echo '<td width="300px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Nome e cognome</b></center></td>';
echo '<td width="120px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Livello</b></center></td>';
echo '<td width="120px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Upgrade</b></center></td>';
echo '<td width="180px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Livello richiesto</b></center></td>';
echo '<td width="120px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Pass</b></center></td>';
echo '<td width="120px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Conferma</b></center></td>';
echo '<td width="100px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Approva</b></center></td>';
echo '<td width="100px" style="border: black 1px solid"><center><b>Nega</b></center></td>';
echo '</tr>';

 while($row_ver_liv_up = mysql_fetch_array($result_ver_liv_up)) 
{
echo '<form method="post" name="ver_liv_up">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center>'.$row_ver_liv_up['id']."</center></td>";
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center>'.$row_ver_liv_up['nome']."&nbsp;" .$row_ver_liv_up['cognome']."</center></td>";
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center>'.$row_ver_liv_up['tipo_user']."</center></td>";
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center>'.$row_ver_liv_up['upgrade_liv']."</center></td>";
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center>';
if ($row_ver_liv_up['tipo_user'] == 'utente'){
echo $utente_piu;}
if ($row_ver_liv_up['tipo_user'] == "delegato"){
echo $delegato_piu;}
echo '</center></td>';
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center>
      <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==\'pass\') this.value=\'\';" /></center></td>';
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center>
      <input name="conferma" type="password" id="pass" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==\'conferma\') this.value=\'\';" /></center></td>';
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center><input style="width: 100px;" name="ver_liv_upg_yes" type="submit" value="Approva" /></center></td>';
echo '<td style="border: black 1px solid"><center><input style="width: 100px;" name="ver_liv_upg_no" type="submit" value="Nega" /></center></td>';
echo '</tr>';

echo '</form>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

it's work!!!